# Line 48 and 62 C++ error Expected unqualified id before if?

Tags: c++

I am programming a simple calculator that subtracts adds divides or multiplies depending on whether you type 1 2 3 or 4. I keep getting this error. Keep in mind I am newer to C++. It happens with the IF lines in Mode == 3 and Mode == 4

```
#include <iostream>

int main(){
using namespace std;
int x;
int y;
int x2;
int y2;
int x3;
int y3;
int x4;
int y4;
int Mode;

cout << "Welcome to Brian's Calculator!";
cout << endl;
cout << "Pick a mode. 1 is Addition. 2 Is Subtraction. 3 is Multiplacation. 4 is          Division";
cin >> Mode;

if (Mode==1){
cout << "You chose addition.";
    cout << endl;
 cout << "Pick a number.";
cout << endl;
cin >> x;
cout << endl;
cout << "Pick another.";
cout << endl;
cin >> y;
cout << "The sum of the numbers you chose are: " << x+y <<".";
return 0;   
   };

 if (Mode==2){
    cout << "You chose subtraction.";
    cout << endl;
     cout << "Pick a number.";
cout << endl;
cin >> x2;
cout << endl;
cout << "Pick another.";
cout << endl;
cin >> y2;
cout << "The difference of the numbers you chose are: " << x2-y2 <<".";}
return 0;
};

if (Mode==3){
    cout << "You chose Multiplacation.";
    cout << endl;
     cout << "Pick a number.";
cout << endl;
cin >> x3;
cout << endl;
cout << "Pick another.";
cout << endl;
cin >> y3;
cout << "The product of the numbers you chose are: " << x3*y3 <<".";
 return 0;
};

 if (Mode==4){
    cout << "You chose Division.";
    cout << endl;
     cout << "Pick a number.";
cout << endl;
cin >> x4;
cout << endl;
cout << "Pick another.";
cout << endl;
cin >> y4;
cout << "The quotient of the numbers you chose are: " << x4/y4 <<".";
return 0;
};
```

Comment: None of those if blocks should have semicolons.

Comment: Please follow C++ naming conventions.  Don't capitalize variables.  Also, you don't need `x2`, `x3`, `x4`, `y2`, `y3`, or `y4`.

Comment: TIP: you don't need to use different variables for every operation, you can use only `x` and `y` for the four operations.

Answer (score 0):

At this line:

```
cout << "The difference of the numbers you chose are: " << x2-y2 <<".";}
```

You have an extra `}`

Answer (score 0):

PROBLEM: you have two end-braces instead of one:

```
if (Mode==2){
...
// DELETE THE EXTRANEOUS "}"!
cout << "The difference of the numbers you chose are: " << x2-y2 <<".";}
return 0;
};
```

SUGGESTED ALTERNATIVE:

```
if (Mode==2){
  ...
  // DELETE THE EXTRANEOUS "}"!
  cout << "The difference of the numbers you chose are: " << x2-y2 <<".";
  return 0;
}
```

EVEN BETTER:

```
  switch (Mode) {
    case 1 :
      ...
      break;

    case 2 :
      ...
      break;
```

Answer (score 0):

On this line you have a misplaced `}`:

```
cout << "The difference of the numbers you chose are: " << x2-y2 <<".";}
                                                                       ^
```

when you fix that you will need an extra `}` after the end of your program to close `main` as well. Also you do not need a `;` after the `}` when you close the *if* statements for example:

```
if (Mode==1){
// code...
};
 ^
```